# Converting base-8 to base-32 without using any other base?

Tags: binary, numbers, radix

I have base-8 number 64276. How would I convert this number directly into base-32 without converting it into binary, decimal or any other base.

Edit: I am trying to solve the problem with pencil and paper

Comment: With difficulty.  5 base-8 digits map cleanly onto 3 base-32 digits, so you'll need to convert each 5-digit chunk separately.  The easiest way is to convert to an `int` first.

Comment: That would constitute converting it to another base Oliver :)

Comment: In a computer it's all just different expressions of binary anyway: in javascript `064276.toString(32)` would handle it. If you want to do it on paper you'll need to use a classical base conversion.

Comment: but number.toString internally converts the whole number into binary, isn't that disallowed?  Or if out-of-the-box answers like that are allowed, then "you" can convert the number by giving it to me, I'll convert it using my calculator, and "you" won't have converted it into any other base! ;-)

Comment: I should clarify that I a, attempting this with pencil and paper...

Comment: @JennaMaiz oh!  pencil and paper is easier, go over the digit stream digit by digit, converting each to 3 binary bits in your head and writing down every 5 binary bits as a base-32 digit.

Comment: Base 8 is plain old "octal" -- 3 bits per digit.  Just like hexadecimal is 4 bits per digit.

Comment: But you will need to convert into "binary, decimal or any other base", since there's no meaningful representation of digits above base 36.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a fun homework challenge, so here's a hint -- how could you convert a 5,000-digit base 64 number into base 32?

Comment: Would you somehow use base 2^5 and group them somehow such that you can factor out something....?

Comment: you can group pairs of octal digits, emit a base-32 digit, and keep track of the multiplicative offset to use for the next pair of octal digits

Comment: How would you do the conversion?  How do you represent a base-32 number?

Comment: base 16 is represented with the symbols [0-9a-f], and that approach extends in the obvious way to base 32 using the symbols [0-9a-v].  The conversion is on pairs of octal digits, going from least to most significant, tracking a carry and a bit offset.  When the bit offset reaches 5, emit two base-32 digits and reset the offset to 0.

Comment: @Andras Could you show how this is done with an example ? I was able to get answer Q5U (in base 32) for by converting octal to binary and then from binary to 32. But please, I would like to know how to go directly from octal to base-32.

Comment: by only converting one or two octal digits to binary at a time, working upward from the units digit.  So 64276, last 6 => 110 too few bits, bring down the 7; 76 => 111110 write 11110 (U) carry the 1, bring down the 2 => 010 + the carried 1 = 0101, too few bits, bring down the 4 => 100 + 010  + 1, write 00101 (5), carry the leading 10, bring down the 6 => 110 + 10, write 11010 (Q).  The full binary string (that we can't use) is Q5U  = 11010.00101.11110, which is the same as 110.100.010.111.110 = 64276.

Comment: @JennaMaiz, when I thought this was a programming assignment, I suggested thinking about the 5000 digit number to hint at doing it just a few digits at a time, and base 64 to hint at grouping digits, since two base 8 digits make one base 64 digit.  Maybe I made the hints too obscure, but I find this fun, so didn't want it to be a spoiler.

Comment: @Andras So you have to convert to binary to before going to base-32...is there any way to go directly ?

Comment: @JennaMaiz, are you looking for an arithmetic expression?  Since 5 octal digits make exactly 3 base-32 digits, and you want to convert a 5-digit number, you can express the value of each base-32 digit as a function of 2 or 3 of the base-8 digits.  With octal digits abcde and base32 ABC, C = e + 8 * d%4, A = a * 4 + (b div 2), B = b%2 * 16 + c * 2 + (d div 2) (I typed this in off the top of my head, I may be off a bit).  This pattern can be repeated for more than 5 octal digits, in groups of 5 (pad with leading zeros as needed)